# Mimic Excel Text Import wizard in Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a requirement to paste the clipboard data to a textbox and split the data into columns as what we can do in Excel Text Import wizard.

[image]

Can anybody suggest me a starting point to get hold of this?

Comment: I don't want to put this as an answer. Just an idea: use a Listbox, set OwnerDraw = true, use a fixed size font and manage mouse click over the higher part (when click get mouse coords, translate to chars count, add computed column to a list and draw vertical line). Not so easy...

Comment: drawing a vertical line is ok... but how to drag that vertical line?

Comment: Possible, but difficult. Trapping MouseDown event you should check if you're on a previous _column separator_. If not, do nothing; otherwise set a bool var to true (telling you're moving a column) and on MouseMove erase previous line and draw new one according to current position. On MouseUp you delete old column (if moving) and add new column. Logic should probably be more complex than this... but I repeat it's just an idea and an hard work!!

Comment: Are you going the way I suggested? Do you want me to add an answer?

Comment: Yap, I am trying your way, if you could add up an answer that will be great...

Comment: Did you find anything that works? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

an idea can be put each character of first line of the text in many TextBox control which created and arranged horizontally in a windows form so an user can separate line by clicking on each text box to show the breaking points

Answer (score 1):

I've found some old CPP code for a control here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/separator_ctrl.aspx

I'm still trying to find an updated version for .NET.  (I'm not sure I have the time to try to convert this, myself.)